# Specify job working directory in Sun Grid Engine

Tags: sungridengine

I can use `-cwd` flag in the script to specify that the script directory is also the job working directory. So I basically have two options:

- specify `-cwd` and set the script directory as the job directory
- omit `-cwd` and do not explicitly set job directory

In the latter case, my job is run in directory specified by my `$HOME` value.
My question is how can I specify job working directory. For example, suppose I have the following directory:

```
|main----------|sub----mydata.txt
|--myscript.sh
```

With the contents of my script being:

```
#!bin/bash
tail mydata.txt -n 1 > output.txt
```

If I specify flag `-cwd` then the job will fail - since there is no `mydata.txt` in my `main` directory - it's found in directory named `sub`. I've tried adding the following commands before my main command:

```
export $HOME=main/sub
```

But it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **-wd** option.  No c required.